# Перенести элемент с одного блока в другой на js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть меню на bs3 и есть фильтр.Меню идет отдельным блоком (обвел синим) а фильтр находится в другом блоке(обвел красным)
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На телефонах и планшетах (ну к примеру max-width:768px) должно быть так что бы фильтр был в меню (указа стрелочками)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> **Как мне перенести фильтр с одного блока в другой при max-width:768px без использования position:absolute**

Comment: может изначально сделать копию и скрыть, а при нужном разрешении показать, а декстопную версии фильтра соот скрыть, когда отображаем мобильную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверняка не самое лучшее решение

```js
function changeTemplate(){
  if($(window).width()<768){
    //при ширине окна менее 768px перемещаем фильтр в шапку
    $('main .filter').prependTo('header');
  }else{
    //в противном случае перемещаем в своё обычное место
    $('header .filter').prependTo('main');
  }
}
$(document).ready(changeTemplate);
$(window).resize(changeTemplate);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
header{
  background-color:#555;
  padding:10px;
  display:flex;
}
.menu{
  background-color:#acd;
  height:30px;
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
main{
  display:flex;
}
.filter{
  background-color:#dac;
  width:200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.content{
  height:100vh;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background-color:#cda;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="menu">меню</div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="filter">фильтр</div>
  <div class="content">контент</div>
</main>
```